# I was trying to build an app using Cordova. But it said build failed and showed an error. Is there a solution to this?

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, build

C:\Users\Me\Library>cordova build android
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk (recommended setting)
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk (DEPRECATED)
Using Android SDK: C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.4/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 34s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file 'C:\Users\Me\Library\platforms\android\settings.gradle' (C:\Users\Me.gradle\caches\7.6\scripts\dqjrgsw17c62wbpoagod92e1e).

> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 65

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.6/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 13s
Command failed with exit code 1: C:\Users\Me\Library\platforms\android\gradlew -b C:\Users\Me\Library\platforms\android\build.gradle cdvBuildDebug

C:\Users\Me\Library>cordova build android
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Alim\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk (recommended setting)
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk (DEPRECATED)
Using Android SDK: C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
Command failed with exit code 1: C:\Users\Me\Library\platforms\android\gradlew -b C:\Users\Me\Library\platforms\android\build.gradle cdvBuildDebug

i was using cordova to build an app but this error occured at the last stage of building it. tried to search for many ways to address this issue, but couldnt find any solutions so far.

I tried installing different versions of gradle, and also changed some environment variables as said on the site, but couldn't get past this point. So far, I've done the process with, gradle 7.6 and gradle 8.4. however this error still pops up at the last minute .

Comment: Please try to properly format your question. As for your your build failure try downgrading your JDK. You seem to be using 21. Try using a [compatible JDK](https://docs.gradle.org/8.4/userguide/compatibility.html#java)

Comment: I'm not even going to attempt to read that. Please edit your post to be readable and clearly state your question. That header isn't a question and is hard to read. Please use proper formatting as well. As is, your post is painful to read.

Comment: @JeremyStyers I'm sorry. It's just that I'm new to all this and don't really know how to properly format a question here...